# Is mounting with "discard" needed for TRIM?

Tags: mount, data-recovery, ssd, trim

I was wondering whether mounting an SSD using the `discard` option (documented in [`man mount`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html)) is actually required for ATA TRIM to be sent to the SSD's controller.

The evidence is a bit circumstantial: Whether or not I mount a partition with `discard` on a [SanDisk SSD PLUS](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12504/%7E/sandisk-ultra-plus-ssd-specifications), deleted files can't be restored by running TestDisk moments after the deletion. File paths are intact, but file content is gone. From this I suspect that TRIM ran on the SSD and made the file contents irrecoverable.

Looking at `systemctl list-timers`, there doesn't seem to be a unit that runs `fstrim`.

Does the kernel send TRIM after file deletion although the partition is not mounted with `discard`? Or is it another reason why TestDisk reliably can't restore files from the SSD?

---

I'm on Arch Linux 5.12.3.

`findmnt` tells me this about the partitions and their mount options:

```
TARGET                       SOURCE     FSTYPE OPTIONS
/                            /dev/sda3  ext4   rw,relatime
└─/sda1                      /dev/sda1  ext4   rw,relatime,lazytime,discard
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the filesystem is mounted with `discard`, then deleting files will automatically cause the TRIM command to be issued. This often has a negative performance impact, so it's generally better not to use that mount option and to instead run `fstrim` periodically, which will work as long as all the block device layers support it (for example, if you're using LUKS for encryption, you'll need to use `cryptsetup --allow-discards`). Unless you use this mount option, the TRIM command will not be automatically sent by the filesystem driver when you unlink files.

You could also try mounting with `nodiscard`. Although this is the default and usually unnecessary, it is possible that your filesystem had continuous TRIM support added to its default options set through `tune2fs -o discard /dev/sda1`. You can remove it with `tune2fs -o ^discard /dev/sda1`.

You might be able to find out what the issue is by using the `debugfs` utility to first list the actual blocks within a file before you delete it, and then directly access those blocks after deletion to see if they have been zeroed or return undisturbed but unallocated data.

Here's a shell script to test whether `debugfs` can read the contents of a deleted file using its block number:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

file=test_file
echo "Current date: $(date)" > "$file"; sync
# Get the device of our test file, for example "/dev/sda1"
device=$(df -P "$file" | awk 'END{print $1}')
# The block of the file's contents, stat gets the inode number
block=$(sudo debugfs -R "blocks <$(stat -c %i "$file")>" "$device")
rm $file; sync
# Read the contents of the deleted file, -D bypasses the buffer cache
sudo debugfs -D -R "block_dump $block" "$device"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've added a script to your answer that demonstrated that debugfs can indeed read the contents of a deleted file from the SSD if the file system is not mounted using `discard` and I don't run `fstrim` after the deletion. The opposite is true as well: debugfs reads zeros from the blocks of the deleted file if the file system is mounted using `discard` or I run `fstrim` after deletion. This also indicates that the [DRAT word](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/243868/whats-the-drat-word-of-my-ssd) of my SSD is zeros.